# Find the value that failed for quickcheck

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

When a value fails a QuickCheck'd test, I'd like to use it for debugging. Is there any way I can do something like:

```
let failValue = quickCheck' myTest
in someStuff failValue
```

If my data was `read`able then I could probably hack some way to get it in from IO, but it's not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I couldn't find anything in the QuickCheck API to do this in a nice way, but here's something I hacked together using the monadic QuickCheck API. It intercepts and logs the inputs to your property in an `IORef`, and assumes that if it failed, the last one was the culprit and returns it in a `Just`. If the test passed, the result is `Nothing`. This can probably be refined a bit but for simple one-argument properties it should do the job.

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.IORef
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.Monadic

prop_failIfZero :: Int -> Bool
prop_failIfZero n = n /= 0

quickCheck' :: (Arbitrary a, Show a) => (a -> Bool) -> IO (Maybe a)
quickCheck' prop = do input <- newIORef Nothing
                      result <- quickCheckWithResult args (logInput input prop)
                      case result of
                         Failure {} -> readIORef input
                         _ -> return Nothing
  where
    logInput input prop x = monadicIO $ do run $ writeIORef input (Just x)
                                           assert (prop x)
    args = stdArgs { chatty = False }

main = do failed <- quickCheck' prop_failIfZero
          case failed of
              Just x -> putStrLn $ "The input that failed was: " ++ show x
              Nothing -> putStrLn "The test passed"
```

Comment: This little trick just made my Haskell debugging experience a lot better. Thanks

Comment: I was struggling myself with this for a while and that post was quite useful to me as food for thoughts, so thanks a lot for that. I thought I'd also drop in here a pointer to `whenFail` (and `wnehFail'`) (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.13.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:whenFail) which take an `IO ()` to perform on failure, and ended up being what I used.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use the [sample'](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/2.4.1.1/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck.html#v%3asample-39-) method, manually run the test and find the values in which it fails. For example, testing a faulty double function:

```
import Test.QuickCheck

double :: Int -> Int
double x | x < 10 = 2 * x
         | otherwise = 13

doubleTest :: Int -> Bool
doubleTest x = x + x == double x

tester :: IO ()
tester = do
  values <- sample' arbitrary
  let failedValues = filter (not . doubleTest) values
  print failedValues
```

The only problem is `sample'` only generates 11 test values, that may not be enough to trigger the bug.