# How do I improve QuickCheck and Parsec debugging?

Tags: haskell, parsec, quickcheck

I am using Haskell and Parsec to parse a file format. My parsing function looks something like:

```
parseInput :: String -> Model
parseInput input = ...

data Model = Model { mNumV :: Int, mNumF :: Int, ... }
```

In order to test this, I am using QuickCheck. I have defined an `Arbitrary` instance that generates a `String` representing the contents of a formatted file:

```
instance Arbitrary File where
    arbitrary = ...

data File = File { fContents :: String, fNumV :: Int, fNumF :: Int, ... }
```

One of my properties might check to determine if `mNumV == fNumV` after parsing the arbitrary `String`. This works well - when it works.

But if something fails, Parsec throws an error similar to:

```
*** Failed (after 1 test):
Exception:
  (line 302, column 3):
  unexpected "\n"
  expecting space
```

This is useful - however, after the test fails the contents of the arbitrary file disappear. I can't go in and reference line 302.

The only alternative that I can see is to print the `fContents` of each arbitrary file after each test - but that seems like a terrible idea. The same goes for routing every arbitrary file to a file on disk for later reference.

Is there a common way around this?

Comment: There is another question about how to return the value that quickCheck failed for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191131/find-the-value-that-failed-for-quickcheck

Comment: @JakobRunge I think I already have that value - I'm missing some way to get the line number from Parsec and do a look up on the file contents.

Comment: If you know how to get the failing value, and Parsec has given you the line and column number, shouldn't you be able to go to that location to see which input is giving the error?

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.5/docs/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#v:parse returns `Either ParseError a` and you can get the sourcepos from `Left err`

Comment: @d8d0d65b3f7cf42 I think that's what I want, thanks - I am going to try it out in a bit. If you want to post an answer, I will accept that as it seems like a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `whenFail` to print the offending string (or dump it to a file) upon failure.